# too many values to unpack [Django]

Tags: python, django

```
def index(request):
    expiring_list = probe.objects.filter("isExpired=True")
    output = ', '.join([p.serial for p in expiring_list])
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

`isExpired` is a Boolean function. How should I modify the filter so that the filter does not raise a `ValueError`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the query in a wrong format.

Your query should be of the form:

```
expiring_list = probe.objects.filter(isExpired = True)
```

This was the query you needed to make in case `isExpired` was your model field. But since you say its a function, assuming that function is inside the class you need to get all the objects in the following way:

```
expiring_list = []

objects = probe.objects.all()

for obj in objects:
    if obj.isExpired() == True:
        expiring_list.append(obj)
```

The expiring_list will now contain all the objects of the model probe where `isExpired` function returns `True`

Comment: IsExpired is a function that uses an expiry date field to output a boolean, so I cannot use it as a normal field

Comment: is isExpired is a function in your class? and expiry_date is a field in your model. If that is the case then you need the following:

objects = probe.objects.all()
for obj in objects:
    if

Comment: If isExpired is a function, the verification should be like this:   `if obj.isExpired():`

Comment: @Arpit Goyal I had to modify the code a bit so that it looks like this:

        if obj.isExpired()==True:

basically the main difference is the parameter brackets after isExpired

Comment: Yeah I am sorry for that.  Well that was an honest mistake :P

Answer (score 1):

I think isExpired is not a field in your models, as reference to your previous question [Refresh a field from another table [Django]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784859/refresh-a-field-from-another-table-django/31784941#31784941)

I think exp_date is the field which you are looking for.

Try this:

```
import datetime

def index(request):
   expiring_list = probe.objects.filter(exp_date__lt=datetime.date.today())
   output = ', '.join([p.serial for p in expiring_list])
   return HttpResponse(output)
```

Comment: The problem here was that I did not know how to call a function, but thanks for this alternative approach :)